# AWS Signer support for websockets in flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, websocket, amazon-kinesis

I was trying to implement AWS Webrtc in flutter. For testing we were trying to connect to [KVS WebRTC Test page](https://awslabs.github.io/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js/examples/index.html) provided by aws.

For signalling websocket APIs are used. We get the Websocket URL from kinesis APIs. But after researching, we found that the websocket must be signed before connecting. Is there any workaround for this?